# path of perl scripts

Tags: perl, apache

I am following the book 'Google Hacks'. It has many ready-made perl scripts, but it does not clearly say exactly where I need to save those perl scripts. I think I have to invoke these scripts from command line, but cannot figure out the location where these scripts should be stored. I am using Strawberry perl.

Also, it would be helpful I can run perl scripts from local environment setting with Internet connection, for example, to scrap Google search results. Thank you

note: I am using Apache webserver and windows 7 operating system

Comment: Depends on what environment you're trying to run them in. Command line Linux/Windows? A webserver (as you sorta allude to in your tags)?

Comment: If you're invoking them from the command line, then it doesn't matter where they are. If you are invoking them from your webserver, then it depends on how you've configured the server.

Answer (score 1):

Are they on your server, or are they on your local machine? I'm assuming they're on your local system:

#### On Unix/Mac/Linux, the setup is fairly straight forward:

- Make sure that the *shebang* points to your Perl executable. I make it `#! /usr/bin/env perl` which will find the `perl` command in my path.
- Put the scripts in a directory in your `$PATH` variable.

#### On Windows, the setup is a bit more involved:

- You need to setup your `%PATH%` environment variable to point to include your Perl scripts. You can do this by going into the System Control Panel (the easiest way is to right click on *Computer* on your desktop, and select *Properties*. Then go into *Advanced Settings*, and click on the *Environment Varables...* button on the bottom. Path is one of the *System Variables*.
- You need to associate your `*.pl` suffix with your Perl executable. The problem is that Microsoft keeps changing this. However, the following works for Windows 7 and earlier:

  - Find a Perl script and view it in Windows Explorer. Right click on it, and open *Properties*. In Properties, there's an *Opens with* selection. Click on the *Change* button and select your Perl interpreter as your interpreter. Make sure the *Always use the selected program to open this kind of file* checkbox is checked.
- Finally, you may want to set `%PATHEXT%` to include `.pl` as one of the executables. This way, you can type your Perl program without having to type the suffix all of the time. On Unix/Linux/Mac, you don't need suffixes because the *shebang* will point to the correct interpreter, but Windows must have a suffix associated with the executable. Now, instead of typing `foo.pl` on the command line, you can just type `foo`.

---

Once this is done, you can simply type in the name of your *executable* Perl script from any directory in the Command Prompt terminal and run your program.

Answer (score 0):

The 1st thing you need to do, is to make sure that the .pl (or as some use, .plx) extension is associated in the windows registry as a perl program and that perl programs should be run by your perl.exe.  At this point you should be able to run perl programs that don't require command line parameters just by double clicking them in Windows Explorer.  I know that the installer for ActiveState Perl does this for you by default.  I can't vouch for Strawberry.

To run them on the command line, you can just name their complete path ( C:\Mypath\Myprog.pl) or put them in a directory named in your PATH environment variable.

If you're trying to run them via Apache, you'll need to configure Apache with a CGI-BIN directory and put your CGI compatible perl programs in that directory.  Again, Apache on Windows depends on the file extension associations in the registry, so make sure you've done that 1st step.